# Change Position Of a UIView programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

[image: ScreenShot]

There is an Arabic Page in my app and The "Date Field" in the Arabic Page must align to the right side of the view(right now, it is to the left). I have tried the following code

```
    -(void)changeDatePosition{
    if (!_isEnglish) {
        CGRect currentDatePostion=_viewForDate.frame;
        [_viewForDate removeFromSuperview];
        currentDatePostion.origin.x+=currentDatePostion.size.width;
        _viewForDate.frame=currentDatePostion;
        [_baseView addSubview:_viewForDate];
    }
}
```

But that did not help. The view positioned itself to the top of the navigation bar(no change in the x co-ordinate,either). I have used autolayout to align the left leading space of "ViewForDate"(the date field) to the leading space of "PlacesView"(The View on Top of the Date Field). But I set its priority to 250. HOw can I solve this problem?

Comment: set x of your view by total full width - veiwofdate width

Comment: @NitinGohel I didnt get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook an IBOutlet to the leading constraint of the date view and set its value to 0. And then try this code:

```
-(void)changeDatePosition{
    if (!_isEnglish) {
        _dateViewLeadConstraint.constant = x;
    }
    //x - amount by which view should move right, you can calculate based on your view setup
}
```

Comment: OK, good. I just saw your solution, and I think it is bit more complex than this. There is no need to change the constraint priorities in my opinion.

Comment: I feared that if I did not work with priorities, the View might just  expand along the width and align both Left and Right with the View on tope. Or the constraints might conflict

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)changeDatePosition{
    if (!_isEnglish) {
        CGRect currentDatePostion=_viewForDate.frame;
        [_viewForDate removeFromSuperview];
        float ScreenWidth=_viewForDate.frame.size.width;
        currentDatePostion.origin.x=ScreenWidth-currentDatePostion.size.width;
        _viewForDate.frame=currentDatePostion;
        [_baseView addSubview:_viewForDate];
    }
}
```

can you try it please.May be it solve your problem

Comment: instead of screenWidth better to use _baseView's width

Comment: but accoding to screen its also gud appraoch

Comment: but user add dateview in _baseView so i suggest to take its width

Comment: It did not help. the view(date view) simply jumped to the navigation bar. the same thing happened when I tried the method i posted

Comment: try now as suggested by nitin

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
currentDatePosition = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - currentDatePosition.size.width, currentDatePosition.frame.origin.y, currentDatePosition.frame.size.width, currentDatePosition.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: This did not work either. The View simply moves to the navigation bar on top

Comment: Does the view's y value change?

Comment: Only the Y value changes. it simply goes to 0 (i think)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem and quite happy about it.

The DateView has a Left Alignment(Leading Space) to Places That is set to 0. I made a right alignment for it too(at 144). Then I created Outlets for them namely, leftAlignment(=0) and rightAlignment(=144) and wrote this method.

```
-(void)changeDateLocation{
    if (!_isEnglish) {
        _leftAlignment.priority=UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow;
        _rightAlignment.constant=0;
        _rightAlignment.priority=UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
    }
    else{
        _leftAlignment.priority=UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
        _rightAlignment.priority=UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow;
        _leftAlignment.constant=0;
    }
}
```

And this gave me my solution. I thank all you people who have contributed. This method is quite useful I think. I am trying this for the first time